# tikz empty row in matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I was able to make a tikz matrix have an empty row by doing

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [matrix of math nodes, nodes=draw]
  {
    a & b & c \\
      &   & |[white]| d \\
    e & f & g \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image: MWE]

But is there a better way of doing this?

ETA

I am aware of the option `nodes in empty cells`. But as it says, it puts nodes in the empty cells. I don't want nodes, or at least don't what to display nodes, in that row. The following

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes, nodes={draw,circle}, nodes in empty cells]
  {
    a & b & c \\
      &   &   \\
    e & f & g \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

gives very different results to

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes, nodes=draw]
  {
    a & b & c \\
      &   &  |[white]| d \\
    e & f & g \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know you can simply increase the row separation of one row with `[...]` after `\\` or of all the rows with `row sep=...` option?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
% one row sep increased:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes, nodes={draw,circle}, nodes in empty cells]
  {
    a & b & c \\[2.6ex]
    e & f & g \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

% all row seps increased 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes, nodes={draw,circle}, nodes in empty cells,
row sep=2.6ex]
  {
    a & b & c \\
    e & f & g \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Both the `tikzpicture`s of my MWE (of course, you have to use only one of them, depending on your needs) give this result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes. From the [PGFPlots manual](http://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) (page 647), we can draw nodes in the empty cells by putting option `nodes in empty cells`, so an empty row (or column) will be displayed.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells]
  {
    a & b & c \\
      &   &   \\
    e & f & g \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. My MWE was too minimal. What if I want to draw the nodes in the first and third rows, but not the second row?

Comment: You can do it. The rows with no entries will result in blank spaces. Try with this code for example `\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
  {
      &   &   \\
    a & b & c \\
      &   &   \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: Very good +1 also to you.

Answer (score 2):

Following code shows why an empty second row with `& & \\` or `& & [white] d\\` produces different results:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes, 
    nodes in empty cells,
    nodes = draw,
    ]
  {
    a & b & c \\
      &   & d  \\
    e & f & g \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see in second row, empty nodes are smaller than the node which contains `d`. Therefore, when you declare an empty row, all nodes have default size which is related to `inner sep`. As soon as you insert a non empty node, this node forces increases row height.

In case that you want to draw nodes in rows 1 and 3 but not in row 2, you can define different styles for each row: `row 1/.style={...}`. Following code defines `draw` for all nodes but a particular `row 2/.style` doesn't draw nodes in second row and also fixes their height.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes, 
    nodes in empty cells,
    nodes = draw,
    row 2/.style = {nodes={draw=none, minimum height=1cm}}
    ]
  {
    a & b & c \\
      &   &   \\
    e & f & g \\
  };

  \draw[red,<->] (A-2-2.south)--(A-2-2.north) node[midway, right] {1 cm};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]